# MVP, best practice for passing row events back to the presenter

Tags: gwt, mvp

I have a CellTable within a GWT MVP view and want to inform the presenter when certain actions are taken on a row.  For example a popup menu is presented for a row, and an action (Delete/Edit/etc.) selected.  There's obviously a SelectionModel that is available via HasData, but how would I use this to pass back the action 'action'.

Is there a standard interface (like HasData) that I could use to pass back to the Presenter?

Answer (score 0):

Usually in GWT MVP View exposes an object that can register event handlers: usually thay come in form of `HasXyxHandlers`, like `HasClickHandlers` or `HasChangeHandlers`.

In case of CellTable it's named differently: [`SelectionModel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/view/client/SelectionModel.html). Just implement in View a method that returns it:

```
SelectionModel<YourClass> getSelectionModel();
```

then Presenter calls this method and registers itself:

```
final SelectionModel<YourClass> selectionModel = view.getSelectionModel();
selectionModel.addSelectionChangeHandler(new SelectionChangeEvent.Handler() {
    @Override
    public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event) {
        YourClass selectedObject = selectionModel.getSelectedObject();
        // do something with selectedObject  
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I have access to the SelectionModel via the hasData interface where I am registering for events.  However, I want to find out what the user really wants to do with the selection.  For example, user clicks on row and popup menu appears.  User selects one of the options (Properties, Download, Delete, ...), at which point I want my Presenter to be told about the choice.

Comment: The code in your example doesn't compile, since the getSelectedObject() method is only defined on the SingleSelectionModel.

Comment: Then use `MultiSelectionModel` and call `getSelectedSet()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about this more, I could be over engineering it.  If I have one popup menu that I reuse in the view, and have the presenter listen to click events on the menu (rather than the CellList), then I can query the CellList selection model through within the handler for the button(s).